# SQL function not returning values in table but it will when ran separately

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-function, sql-server-2019

I have a function that for some reason is not bringing back data in the table, but if I cut down the code and test it by itself it works.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ReportingCyclesForReporting]
(
    @ReportingCycleId BIGINT
)
RETURNS @t TABLE
(
    [ReportingCycleId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [BusinessId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ScenarioId] [bigint] NULL,
    [SourceReportingCycleId] [bigint] NULL,
    [MjMEPerDay] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
    [AssetAppreciation] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [LandAssetAppreciation] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [OffFarmAssetAppreciation] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
    [RolledOverDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Archived] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Essential] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [EssentialsLeasedLandValue] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
    [EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
    [EssentialsWaterValue] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
    [RolloverDataOverwrite] [bit] NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @businessId INT
    DECLARE @scenarioId INT
    DECLARE @essential BIT

    -- Get businessid and scenario id for this reporting cycle
    SELECT @businessId = BusinessId
         , @scenarioId = ScenarioId
         , @essential = Essential
      FROM ReportingCycle
     WHERE Id          = @ReportingCycleId
       AND Archived    = 0
       BEGIN
    IF @scenarioId IS NOT NULL
    begin
        -- Scenario reporting cycle siblings of the given reporting cycle
        INSERT INTO @t(
               ReportingCycleId
             , BusinessId
             , StartDate
             , EndDate
             , ScenarioId
             , SourceReportingCycleId
             , MjMEPerDay
             , AssetAppreciation
             , LandAssetAppreciation
             , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
             , RolledOverDate
             , Version
             , Archived
             , Essential
             , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
             , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
             , EssentialsWaterValue
        )
        SELECT rc.Id
             , rc.BusinessId
             , rc.StartDate
             , rc.EndDate
             , rc.ScenarioId
             , rc.SourceReportingCycleId
             , rc.MjMEPerDay
             , rc.AssetAppreciation
             , rc.LandAssetAppreciation
             , rc.OffFarmAssetAppreciation
             , rc.RolledOverDate
             , rc.Version
             , rc.Archived
             , rc.Essential
             , rc.EssentialsLeasedLandValue
             , rc.EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
             , rc.EssentialsWaterValue
          FROM ReportingCycle
        INNER JOIN ReportingCycle rc ON rc.ScenarioId = ReportingCycle.ScenarioId AND rc.Archived = 0
         WHERE ReportingCycle.Id = @ReportingCycleId
           AND ReportingCycle.Archived = 0
        ORDER BY rc.StartDate
        end
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FutureReportingCycles(@businessId, @essential) WHERE Id = @reportingCycleId)
    begin
        -- Future reporting cycles
        INSERT INTO @t(
               ReportingCycleId
             , BusinessId
             , StartDate
             , EndDate
             , ScenarioId
             , SourceReportingCycleId
             , MjMEPerDay
             , AssetAppreciation
             , LandAssetAppreciation
             , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
             , RolledOverDate
             , Version
             , Archived
             , Essential
             , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
             , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
             , EssentialsWaterValue
        )
        SELECT Id
             , BusinessId
             , StartDate
             , EndDate
             , ScenarioId
             , SourceReportingCycleId
             , MjMEPerDay
             , AssetAppreciation
             , LandAssetAppreciation
             , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
             , RolledOverDate
             , Version
             , Archived
             , Essential
             , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
             , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
             , EssentialsWaterValue
        FROM FutureReportingCycles(@businessId, @essential)
        END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM HistoryReportingCycles(@businessId, @essential) WHERE Id = @reportingCycleId and ScenarioId is null)
    BEGIN
        -- History reporting cycles
        INSERT INTO @t(
               ReportingCycleId
             , BusinessId
             , StartDate
             , EndDate
             , ScenarioId
             , SourceReportingCycleId
             , MjMEPerDay
             , AssetAppreciation
             , LandAssetAppreciation
             , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
             , RolledOverDate
             , Version
             , Archived
             , Essential
             , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
             , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
             , EssentialsWaterValue
        )
        SELECT Id
             , BusinessId
             , StartDate
             , EndDate
             , ScenarioId
             , SourceReportingCycleId
             , MjMEPerDay
             , AssetAppreciation
             , LandAssetAppreciation
             , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
             , RolledOverDate
             , Version
             , Archived
             , Essential
             , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
             , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
             , EssentialsWaterValue
        FROM HistoryReportingCycles(@businessId, @essential)  where  ScenarioId is null
        END
    ELSE
    -- Now
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t(
               ReportingCycleId
             , BusinessId
             , StartDate
             , EndDate
             , ScenarioId
             , SourceReportingCycleId
             , MjMEPerDay
             , AssetAppreciation
             , LandAssetAppreciation
             , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
             , RolledOverDate
             , Version
             , Archived
             , Essential
             , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
             , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
             , EssentialsWaterValue
        )
        SELECT Id
             , BusinessId
             , StartDate
             , EndDate
             , ScenarioId
             , SourceReportingCycleId
             , MjMEPerDay
             , AssetAppreciation
             , LandAssetAppreciation
             , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
             , RolledOverDate
             , Version
             , Archived
             , Essential
             , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
             , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
             , EssentialsWaterValue
        FROM ReportingCycle WHERE id = @ReportingCycleId and Archived = 0
    END

    END
    RETURN 

END
```

I will execute this to trigger it to test

```
  select * from ReportingCyclesForReporting(14212)
```

This happens when it's a future reporting cycle. I will get an empty table returned. I've debugged this in Visual Studio and I can see that it goes into the correct branch with the correct values but the table returns nothing.

But if I run a cut down version of the script brings back the values.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
[ReportingCycleId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[BusinessId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ScenarioId] [bigint] NULL,
[SourceReportingCycleId] [bigint] NULL,
[MjMEPerDay] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
[AssetAppreciation] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[LandAssetAppreciation] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[OffFarmAssetAppreciation] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[RolledOverDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Version] [int] NOT NULL,
[Archived] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Essential] [bit] NOT NULL,
[EssentialsLeasedLandValue] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
[EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
[EssentialsWaterValue] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
[RolloverDataOverwrite] [bit] NULL
)
    INSERT INTO @t(
           ReportingCycleId
         , BusinessId
         , StartDate
         , EndDate
         , ScenarioId
         , SourceReportingCycleId
         , MjMEPerDay
         , AssetAppreciation
         , LandAssetAppreciation
         , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
         , RolledOverDate
         , Version
         , Archived
         , Essential
         , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
         , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
         , EssentialsWaterValue
    )
    SELECT Id
         , BusinessId
         , StartDate
         , EndDate
         , ScenarioId
         , SourceReportingCycleId
         , MjMEPerDay
         , AssetAppreciation
         , LandAssetAppreciation
         , OffFarmAssetAppreciation
         , RolledOverDate
         , Version
         , Archived
         , Essential
         , EssentialsLeasedLandValue
         , EssentialsShareFarmedLandValue
         , EssentialsWaterValue
    FROM FutureReportingCycles(306, 0)

    select * from @t
```

This will bring back the values

[image]

Here is a picture of it in debug mode showing it goes into that branch.

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Without a [mre] its going to be very difficult for anyone to assist with this.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, I was hoping there was something glaringly obvious with the function that stood out.

Comment: I think you're down to good old fashioned debugging... run your complete function code in a query window and print out every step to see whats going wrong. Probably a null value or something. But not obvious.

Comment: Is condition " ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM HistoryReportingCycles(@businessId, @essential) WHERE Id = @reportingCycleId and ScenarioId is null)" returns tru?

Comment: No, it only goes in the future branch.

When running in debug above the picture shows the only branch it appears to go in for the function

Comment: It looks like you call another function FutureReportingCycles - is it possible that the issue is in that function rather than this one?  I'd have an Extended Event trace running at the same time to track the actual T-SQL statements PLUS the permissions checks - although I suspect you'd see permissions errors bubbling up if it was something like ownership chains

Comment: No the FutureReportingCycles works fine. in the last code snipped where I have a cut down version that uses that function it returns the values fine

Comment: BTW the picture I have shown shows the same values going into the stored procedure in debug mode inside the else if branch of future, but does not return any values.

Comment: Might be that I'm missing something (had no coffee by now), but shouldn't it end with `RETURN @t` instead of `RETURN`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

 but what it's returning is defined up the top ' RETURNS @t TABLE'